# Node.js .env load problem file problem - variable is loading as undefined

Tags: node.js, environment

I'm building bot with discord.js. Everything was working just fine, but when I run code today I got error that TOKEN that I load from .env file is invalid. I checked it and TOKEN is "undefined". My folder tree look like it:

- Bot folder

  - Node.js file (bot.js)
  - .env file

I'm loading variables with:

```
const TOKEN = process.env.TOKEN;
```

In .env file I assign TOKEN like it.

```
TOKEN=my-bot-token
```

Any ideas? I was restarting my code editor (VS Code) few times. Exactly the same code worked some time ago...

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`const TOKEN = process.env.TOKEN;` does not load anything from your .env. You need to use something like [dotenv](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv):

```
const { parsed, error } = require('dotenv').config();

if (error) {
  // Handle error
  throw error;
}

console.log(parsed);
```

Also notice:

> As early as possible in your application, require and configure
> dotenv.

**Edit:** You can also set the [path](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv#path) to your .env:

```
const { parsed, error } = require('dotenv').config({
  path: '/full/custom/path/to/your/env/vars'
});
```

Answer (score 2):

A very simple approach would just be to type this following command right next to your import statements.

```
require('dotenv').config();
```

Then, you can just use your regular forms of accessing the variables. Such as:

```
process.env.TOKEN
```

Comment: Yea, sorry I didn’t include it in my answer I’ve done it too

Comment: Check discord and make sure you didn't get a message from the discord team. If discord recognizes your token in the public, it disables it and sends you a message to create a new one. If that's not the case, try "console.log(process.env.TOKEN)" and tell me what result you get. Is that the approach you did to get "undefined" ?

Comment: Yes, that token is undefined

Comment: I approach undefined this way

Comment: Instead of using process.env, try hardcoding in the value for the token. So, just type in your value for TOKEN where you need it. Then, tell me if you're still getting an error.

Comment: If I'm making it like this:
`const TOKEN = 'my bot token'`
It's working just fine.

Comment: Try pzaenger's solution and edit your original message to show the error that is logged.

Comment: I found a problem, my program was getting a bad path, I checked it with pzaenger help. Now I should just take .env file from some diffrent path, I saw this already in Stackoverflow, well thank you so much for help!

Comment: No problem. I just saw this error too in StackOverflow when I was researching possible problems when using process.env